# Keeping Specific Dates AND Distinct NULLS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetFeedDate10_TEST]
    -- sp_GetFeedDate10_TEST '05/30/2018'
    @daycurrent DATE
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        TANK.Name, TANK.Tank_Pond_uID, 
        FEED.FeedValue, FEED.Date
    FROM
        aa_Tanks_Ponds TANK 
    LEFT JOIN
        aa_Feed_Chart FEED ON TANK.Tank_Pond_uID = FEED.Tank_Pond_uID
    WHERE
        TANK.Site_Name = 'Dry Creek' --and (FEED.Date = DATEADD(DAY, -10, @daycurrent))
    ORDER BY
        TANK.Tank_Pond_uID
END
```

I commented out the "and

```
(FEED.Date = DATEADD(DAY, -10, @daycurrent))
```

where I am currently having issues with filtering. The join is pulling a list of tanks and joining with any feed values and dates from another list.

Where I run into trouble is when filtering based on the date, I lose all the distinct NULLS for all tanks that don't contain a value. It's important to keep the result the same rows and order as the TANK table.

Here's and example of the first table:

```
Name  Tank_Pond_uID 
--------------------
B01  DCB01
B02  DCB02
B03  DCB03
B04  DCB04
B05  DCB05
```

Example of the second table:

```
Site_Name   Tank_Pond_uID   Date         FeedValue
--------------------------------------------------
Dry Creek   DCB01           2018-05-20      90
Dry Creek   DCB02           2018-05-20      90
Dry Creek   DCB03           2018-05-20      90
```

Where I run the above stored procedure with a date:

```
sp_GetFeedDate10_TEST '05/30/2018'
```

(I know date doesn't matter as the commented out section needs it), I get the following result:

```
Name    Tank_Pond_uID   FeedValue   Date
-----------------------------------------------
B01     DCB01               90      2018-05-20
B01     DCB01               90      2018-05-21
B01     DCB01               90      2018-05-22
B02     DCB02               90      2018-05-20
B02     DCB02               90      2018-05-21
B02     DCB02               90      2018-05-22
B03     DCB03              NULL     NULL
B04     DCB04              NULL     NULL
B05     DCB05              NULL     NULL
```

When I add the commented section back into the Store procedure and run it again I get the following result:

```
Name    Tank_Pond_uID   FeedValue   Date
-----------------------------------------------
B01     DCB01              90       2018-05-20
B02     DCB02              90       2018-05-20
```

I would like the expected result to be keep the Left rows and still filter date:

Example of expected table result:

```
Name    Tank_Pond_uID   FeedValue   Date
-----------------------------------------------
B01     DCB01              90       2018-05-20
B02     DCB02              90       2018-05-20
B03     DCB03             NULL      NULL
B04     DCB04             NULL      NULL
B05     DCB05             NULL      NULL
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: MSSQL,  Sorry I forgot to mention that.
Using SQL Server Management Studio v17.5

Comment: http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix I would also avoid names like _TEST. You would have to change the name when going to prod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have turned your left join into an inner join with the predicates in your where clause. Move the date predicate to the join and this will work.

```
select TANK.Name
    , TANK.Tank_Pond_uID
    , FEED.FeedValue,FEED.Date 
from aa_Tanks_Ponds TANK 
LEFT JOIN aa_Feed_Chart FEED ON TANK.Tank_Pond_uID = FEED.Tank_Pond_uID
                            and FEED.Date = DATEADD(DAY, -10, @daycurrent)
where TANK.Site_Name = 'Dry Creek' 
order by TANK.Tank_Pond_uID
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  This was indeed where I messed up.  I will keep this in mind when working with JOINS.